# Converting a datatype after a file read

Tags: c++

In our code base, each variable is read from a dump file using `fread` using the standard syntax. However, a new version has an existing variable `foo` converted from `int` to `float`. Therefore, there needs to be a type conversion for the old version of dump file:

```
if(version<v1){
  int temp_var;
  fread(&temp_var, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
  foo = static_cast<float>(temp_var);
}
else{
  fread(&foo, sizeof(float), 1, fp);
}
```

Is this a valid approach? My concern is that `fread` uses file pointer directly to reference the variable. However, I am concerned about the scope of value saved in `foo` outside this function.

What would be a more robust approach to convert and save the variable to `foo`?

Comment: `staitc_cast<float>` !!??! Why is this tagged `C`?

Comment: Your "read as int" and "read as float" pseudocodes are are not rigorously defined for me.  What do those things mean to you?  Perhaps you meant `fread(&temp_var, sizeof(int), 1, stream);` and `fread(&foo, sizeof(float), 1, stream);`  Also, what do you perceive as less robust about your solution?  You should check the return value of `fread`, for one.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable approach to me, providing the version checking is reliable. I  don't understand your concerns, I mean I'm not getting what exactly it is that you are concerned about.

Comment: Do not tag C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages.

Comment: @wyck I meant the same about `fread` and updated the post. That `foo` is not local to this function alone. Concern is if this change would reflect everywhere of `foo` robustly.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I was not sure about my implementation.  I thought tagging `C` would bring wider visibility and perhaps better solution.

Comment: It sounds like you're anticipating a problem you don't have yet.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Will keep this in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code does not make visible how the `foo` variable was passed. If it is like:

```cpp
void versioned_read(float foo)
```

the value will be copied and the actual variable in the outer scope will not be changed. You should pass the reference or pointer to `foo`:

```cpp
void versioned_read(float& foo)
```

Then the approach will work but try to read first to *local* `int` or `float`, then to do direct assignment if it is not memory-critical